# How to vlookup a column from multiple sheets in the same column - google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have multiple sheets in a google sheet workbook consisting of a `person`, `value`, and `percent` column. The sheets are `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`:

[image]
[image]
[image]

What I would like to do is create a formula in a new sheet `Ranks` that takes these values from multiple sheets so that I can sort by `percent`, like so:

[image]

Where an additional column is added to denote which sheet that `person` belonged to.

I have tried many things to no avail. VLOOKUP, ARRAYFORMULA, HLOOKUP, INDEX MATCH combinations, and more.

Comment: Add extra column in every sheet with sheet name, then use VSTACK to get all sheets into one and wrap it with SORT

Comment: Thanks. In my actual data, my selections in each sheet aren't right next to eachother. How would I go about this? ie instead of `A1:B10` I want `A1:A10,C1:10`, but if I put that in a vstack it just stacks `A1:A10` and `C1:C10`. I figured I'd be able to put ths in brackets to fix it but that didn't work.

Comment: First create HSTACK's for each sheet and then VSTACK it together. For example this formula takes A1:A10 and C1:C10 from sheets Sheet2 and Sheet3: =VSTACK(HSTACK(Sheet2!A1:A10,Sheet2!C1:C10),HSTACK(Sheet3!A1:A10,Sheet3!C1:C10))

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can try:

`=REDUCE({"Person","Sheet","Value","Percent"},{"foo";"bar";"baz"},LAMBDA(a,c,{a;QUERY(IFNA(HSTACK(c,INDIRECT(c&"!A2:C")),c),"select Col2, Col1, Col3, Col4 where Col2 is not null",)}))`

Answer (score 1):

If your sheets have different column arrangements, you could use a series of queries to bring them together, and then an overall query to filter and sort your data.

Adapt each sheet query to suit.

Something like this:

```
=query({
query(foo!A:C,"select Col1,'foo',Col2,Col3",1);
query(bar!A:C,"select Col1,'bar',Col2,Col3",1);
query(baz!A:C,"select Col1,'baz',Col2,Col3",1)
},"where Col3 is not null order by Col4 desc label Col2 'sheet'",1)
```

[image]